# Python requests equivalent of urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm trying to authenticate and download some images from a NASA Modis product.
As an example, let's take an hdf file from [this folder](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GQ.061/2000.05.14) (not jpg, which is visible without authentication).

I was able to authenticate and download using urllib (code follows); still, I would like to use requests for this task.
I can't find any useful result online. I know I can just use urllib, but I usually rely on requests and this problem is bugging my head. I think curiosity is a good enough reason. ;)

I have this **working** python script to download a file, based on urllib:

```
url = "https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GQ.061/2000.05.14/MOD09GQ.A2000135.h20v02.061.2020042041314.hdf"

password_manager = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, "https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov", username, password)
CJ = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager),
    urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(CJ))
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as resp:
    with open("im.hdf", "wb") as _fb:
        _fb.write(resp.read())
```

For the sake of the example, I read the response and write it in a local file, which is perfectly readable.

I would like to perform the same task using requests.
I tried:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    _auth = (username, password)
    with s.get(url, auth=_auth) as resp:
        print(resp.status_code)
        print(resp.headers)
```

I also tried using HTTPBasicAuth from requests.auth:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    _auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
    with s.get(url, auth=_auth) as resp:
        print(resp.status_code)
        print(resp.headers)
```

And authenticating the session:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.auth = (username, password)
    with s.get(url) as resp:
        print(resp.status_code)
        print(resp.headers)
```

I always get **error 401**, and the headers dict contains:

```
'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Please enter your Earthdata Login credentials. If you do not have a Earthdata Login, create one at https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov//users/new"'
```

The content of the response (`resp.content`) is:

```
b'HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n'
```

I'm using:

- **Python** 3.8.10 - Linux (WSL)
- **urllib** doesn't show up in pip freeze and doesn't have a __version __ attribute, I'm not sure how to check
- **requests**==2.28.1
- **requests-oauthlib**==1.3.1 (not sure if it is relevant)

If I can provide any other detail let me know.